# Android AlarmManager stops firing after long periods of time

Tags: android, persistence, alarmmanager, alarm, intervals

What is the proper context in which AlarmManagers should be declared and initialized so that they persist indefinitely (or until a system reboot or until a Task Killer wipes it out, realistically) and avoid garbage collection-   But also allow for changes to the alarm across the scope of the entire application.

The whole reason I am using an AlarmManager is to remedy the need to have a service running at all times.  However to accomplish this feat, where is the AlarmManager created?  I would imagine it cannot be created in a service that is then turned off/destroyed because the alarm object would go away with it, eventually, and the alarms would stop firing- would it not?

I liked the idea of the AlarmManager example from a different question post, where a MyAlarm class is created as an extension of the BroadcastReceiver for the alarm's onReceive and the AlarmManager is intialized in this class' constructor.  But how does this implementation work if a MyAlarm instance is required across multiple contexts.  Such as, from event handlers across multiple Activity objects.   From the event handlers of multiple Widgets.  From within a worker service.  All of which may have to disable or enable the alarm.   My guess is, create a local instance everywhere you need to deal with the alarm and because the pendingIntent is the same for all instances, you will in effect be working with a virtual "singleton".

This is only conceptual at this point because I have no idea how I would test "garbage collection" of an Alarm Manager which could occur 8, 12, ? hours later when my alarm just randomly stops firing.   My goal is, if the phone isn't rebooted, and my Task isn't manually killed by the user, to keep the alarm firing indefinitely.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In android the OS automatically closes services it thinks aren't being used... lots of apps and particularly widgets struggle with this.  I don't know if there is a definitive way to make sure the service doesn't close itself.  You can persist it longer by having it occasionally do something so the system doesn't think it's a useless task.

And yes, you'd use the same pending intent for all those, so you can just run one service with multiple handlers linked to it, that's part of the benefit of the way the OS is set up.  You can update all widgets with your signature at the start of your single service, that service can also receive all the handlers from your widgets.

Comment: Sorry- my goal was to use AlarmManager so that my Service does not need to remain running.  The alarm would in fact start the service and the service would then shut off after finished working.   The real question is, where do I intialize this AlarmManager instance for a given pendingIntent so that it remains running forever, even if, say the service it was originally declared is no longer running?

Comment: A service is just a background process that persists so that you can do things like keep a listener open.  You can't initialize AlarmManager so that it "runs forever" you init it in a service and keep that service running.  Like I said you can persist it by doing something occasionally so the OS doesn't think it's a dead process.   People use the on screen wake handles a lot, that way whenever the user wakes the phone you do something.  Since that's usually often enough to make sure the OS doesn't kill the service I would try that.

Answer (score 0):

> However to accomplish this feat, where is the AlarmManager created?

The `AlarmManager` is a system service. It is "created" by the operating system.

> I would imagine it cannot be created in a service that is then turned off/destroyed because the alarm object would go away with it, eventually, and the alarms would stop firing- would it not?

The `AlarmManager` is a system service. The "alarm" are held by the operating system.

> My guess is, create a local instance everywhere you need to deal with the alarm and because the pendingIntent is the same for all instances, you will in effect be working with a virtual "singleton".

Correct.

Comment: A system service created by the OS.   That helps be conceptualize this, thanks!  So, once a repeating alarm (pendingIntent) is scheduled, the alarm should go off indefinitely, unless the app is force closed, task killed, alarm programmatically canceled, or the device is rebooted? It doesn't matter where the setRepeating(PI) is called from?  Does the PI have to be a static object or anything special to make this alarm last forever under normal circumstances.  Thanks

Comment: @user1359312: The only other scenario that *might* cause a problem with alarms is when an app gets upgraded, though I have not been able to reproduce that. Otherwise, your list seems fairly complete. "It doesn't matter where the setRepeating(PI) is called from?" -- correct. "Does the PI have to be a static object or anything special to make this alarm last forever under normal circumstances." -- no.

Comment: I still have this problem. I start a repeating alarm to run BroadcastReceiver.onReceive every five minutes. It runs nicely for 5-6 days, then it gets killed. Test phone is a Huawei P Smart.

Comment: @Franco: Huawei may be imposing restrictions to cut down on background power use. Android itself also kicks apps into "app standby" states if the user does not interact with the app periodically.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. Yes, I have the suspicion that – although I use ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, that keeps the app Standby Bucket constantly equals to 5 – after 5-6 days EMUI decides that enough is enough and kills the app anyway. It happens with other apps too. However it does NOT happen with Samsung Health, which seems indestructible, even if I leave it alone for months. Are they somehow "factory whitelisted" in EMUI?

Comment: @Franco: I cannot rule that out, though I would be somewhat surprised, given that Samsung and Huawei are competitors. However, at the same time, I would be surprised if Samsung Health is using `AlarmManager`.